# How to define constant like this in lisp?

Tags: python, common-lisp

In python it's possible to do this

```
EMPTY, PAWN, KNIGHT, BISHOP, ROOK, QUEEN, KING, BPAWN = range(8)
```

How would you do equivalent in lisp?

Answer (score 11):

It would be more idiomatic in Lisp to just use symbols. Typically as self-evaluating keyword symbols:

```
(defparameter *chess-pieces*
  '(:EMPTY :PAWN :KNIGHT :BISHOP :ROOK :QUEEN :KING :BPAWN))
```

There are reasons to define numeric values - sometimes. Especially when you need to talk to foreign functions. In Lisp you would by default use symbols.

Common Lisp does not have a real enumeration type. Using symbols in a dynamically typed language has some advantages over using numeric variables. For example during debugging the variable contents are more descriptive:

Compare:

```
> (setf c4 queen)

> c4
6
```

vs.

```
> (setf c4 :queen)

> c4
:queen
```

In the latter example the symbol value is self-descriptive.

Comment: I can't use symbols since I need to encode the piece information as part of "move" variable later on. I guess I'll just use defconstant :)

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you can't just use the symbols?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have defined the convenience function `range` somewhere (`(defun range (n) (loop :for i :from 0 :below n :collect i))`), you could set up some local values like this:

```
(destructuring-bind (EMPTY PAWN KNIGHT BISHOP ROOK QUEEN KING BPAWN)
    (range 8)
  #| do stuff |#)
```

However, enumerations like this are seldomly used in Lisp code, since keywords (or other symbols) provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

What about writing a macro to do this? An example:

```
(defmacro defenum (&rest args)
  (let ((counter 0))
    `(progn
       ,@(mapcar (lambda (arg)
                   (cond ((symbolp arg)
                          (prog1
                              `(defparameter ,arg ,counter)
                            (incf counter)))
                         ((listp arg)
                          (prog1
                              `(defparameter ,(first arg) ,(second arg))
                            (setf counter (1+ (second arg)))))
                         (t (error "broken defenum"))))
                 args))))
```

Examples of usage:

```
(defenum x (y 2) z)

(defenum EMPTY PAWN KNIGHT BISHOP ROOK QUEEN KING BPAWN)
```

(it's probably very easy to improve on this example :-) - I prefer `defparameter` to `defconstant` so that's something you may want to change)

Answer (score 1):

One can use `macrolet` to compute a form which sets a bunch of constants:

```
(macrolet ((defenumvalues (&rest names)
             `(progn
                ,@(loop for n in names and i from 0
                        collect `(defconstant ,n ,i))
                (values))))
  (defenumvalues empty pawn knight bishop rook queen king bpawn))
```

Alternative: writing a global macro with `defmacro`.

The general advantage of using a macro (local or global) to define a bunch of constants: the compiler expands the expression and then sees a bunch of `cl:defconstant` forms.

Comment: why create another answer instead of editing your own existing one?

Comment: @sds: different approach with macrolet.

Answer (score 0):

Use defconstant:

```
 (defconstant name initial-value-form [ documentation-string ])
```

For example:

```
(defconstant myvar 5)
```

Comment: I know defconstant, I want to know how I can define a list of constants at once

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
(let ((c 0))
  (dolist (piece '(EMPTY PAWN KNIGHT BISHOP ROOK QUEEN KING BPAWN))
    (eval `(defconstant ,piece ,c)) 
    (incf c)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple macro that I used to do just that:

```
(defmacro enum-constants (&rest constants)
 `(progn ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (key value) `(defconstant ,key ,value))
                   constants (loop for i from 0 below (length constants) collecting i))))
```