# Python's range() analog in Common Lisp

Tags: python, common-lisp, number-sequence

**How to create a list of consecutive numbers in Common Lisp?**

In other words, what is the equivalent of Python's `range` function in Common Lisp?

In Python `range(2, 10, 2)` returns `[2, 4, 6, 8]`, with first and last arguments being optional.  I couldn't find the idiomatic way to create a sequence of numbers, though Emacs Lisp has `number-sequence`.

Range could be emulated [using loop macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872032/596361), but i want to know the accepted way to generate a sequence of numbers with start and end points and step.

Related: [Analog of Python's range in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909856/analog-of-pythons-range-in-scheme)

Comment: I implemented something similar to this using a `delay` and `force`. That mimicked the Python `range`.

Comment: @Vatine, True, but also depending on the python version of course.

Comment: The accepted way to generate a sequence of numbers with start and end points and step is using LOOP or to use a library function, often called IOTA.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no built-in way of generating a sequence of numbers, the canonical way of doing so is to do one of:

- Use `loop`
- Write a utility function that uses `loop`

An example implementation would be (this only accepts counting "from low" to "high"):

```
(defun range (max &key (min 0) (step 1))
   (loop for n from min below max by step
      collect n))
```

This allows you to specify an (optional) minimum value and an (optional) step value.

To generate odd numbers: `(range 10 :min 1 :step 2)`

Comment: I tried this function, if I use (range 10) it works but when I try (range 10 1) I get a backtrace in SBCL which says `odd number of &KEY arguments
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]` If I try (range 10 1 1) I get `unknown &KEY argument: 1
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]` I'm just begining with CL can some one point me on what I'm doing wrong here? I'm using SBCL

Comment: @copyninja You need to call it as `(range 10 :min 1)` or `(range 10 :step 1)`.

Answer (score 21):

alexandria implements scheme's iota:

```
(ql:quickload :alexandria)
(alexandria:iota 4 :start 2 :step 2)
;; (2 4 6 8)
```

Comment: Pointing that the [cl21](http://cl21.org/) library integrates it along with some other related constructs (`map-iota`, `take`,…).

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I'd approach the problem:

```
(defun generate (from to &optional (by 1))
  #'(lambda (f)
      (when (< from to)
        (prog1 (or (funcall f from) t)
          (incf from by)))))

(defmacro with-generator ((var from to &optional (by 1)) &body body)
  (let ((generator (gensym)))
    `(loop with ,generator = (generate ,from ,to ,by)
        while
          (funcall ,generator
                   #'(lambda (,var) ,@body)))))

(with-generator (i 1 10)
    (format t "~&i = ~s" i))
```

But this is just the general idea, there's a lot of room for improvement.

---

OK, since there seems to be a discussion here. I've assumed that what is really needed is the analogue to Python's `range` generator function. Which, in certain sense generates a list of numbers, but does it so by yielding a number each iteration (so that it doesn't create more then one item at a time). Generators are a somewhat rare concept (few languages implement it), so I assumed that the mention of Python suggested that this exact feature is desired.

Following some criticism of my example above, here's a different example that illustrates the reason to why a generator might be used rather then a simple loop.

```
(defun generate (from to &optional (by 1))
  #'(lambda ()
      (when (< from to)
        (prog1 from
          (incf from by)))))

(defmacro with-generator
    ((var generator &optional (exit-condition t)) &body body)
  (let ((g (gensym)))
    `(do ((,g ,generator))
         (nil)
       (let ((,var (funcall ,g)))
         (when (or (null ,var) ,exit-condition)
           (return ,g))
         ,@body))))

(let ((gen
       (with-generator (i (generate 1 10) (> i 4))
         (format t "~&i = ~s" i))))
  (format t "~&in the middle")
  (with-generator (j gen (> j 7))
    (format t "~&j = ~s" j)))

;; i = 1
;; i = 2
;; i = 3
;; i = 4
;; in the middle
;; j = 6
;; j = 7
```

This is, again, only an illustration of the purpose of this function. It is probably wasteful to use it for generating integers, even if you need to do that in two steps, but generators are best with parsers, when you want to yield a more complex object which is built based upon the previous state of the parser, for example, and a bunch of other things. Well, you can read an argument about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: It's unclear to me what you win over (loop for i from 1 below 10 by 1 ...).

Comment: You have implemented much more than the OP asked for and in a sub-optimal way. For example: the name for the function 'GENERATE' is a poor choice. WITH-GENERATOR expands into complex code which then expands into more complex code via LOOP -> terrible during debugging. You also pass a closure to another closure for each generated item. What a waste.

Comment: The original question is: 'How to create a list of consecutive numbers in Common Lisp?' You have answered a different question: 'How to print numbers from 1 to 10 using some kind of 'generators'.'

Comment: This is good food for thought. Under the covers, Python implements range using a lazy/generative style, similar to Clojure's range function. If the desired usage is 1 to 10, loop is fine. If it's 1 to 10 billion, then you should probably use a lazy sequence (as Python indeed does), certainly possible in Common Lisp but not standardized.

Comment: You can use the `series` library for lazy sequences, transducers etc.

Answer (score 5):

Using recursion:

```
(defun range (min max &optional (step 1))
  (when (<= min max)
    (cons min (range (+ min step) max step))))
```

Answer (score 3):

In simple form specifying start, stop, step:

```
(defun range (start stop step) 
  (do (
    (i start (+ i step)) 
    (acc '() (push i acc))) 
   ((>= i stop) (nreverse acc))))
```

Comment: +1 for using do instead of loop. I, for one, have yet to overcome the mental block to loop that I established while reading Graham's _ANSI Common Lisp_

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [snakes](https://github.com/BnMcGn/snakes):

"Python style generators for Common Lisp. Includes a port of itertools."

It is available in [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/releases.html). There may be other Common Lisp libraries that can help.

Answer (score 1):

Not finding what I wanted nor wanting to use an external package, I ended  up writing my own version which differs from the python version (hopefully improving on it) and avoids loop. If you think it is really inefficient and can improve on it, please do.

```
;; A version of range taking the form (range [[first] last [[step]]]).
;; It takes negative numbers and corrects STEP to the same direction
;; as FIRST to LAST then returns a list starting from FIRST and
;; ending before LAST
(defun range (&rest args)
  (case (length args)                                                      
    ( (0) '())                                                             
    ( (1) (range 0 (car args) (if (minusp (car args)) -1 1)))           
    ( (2) (range (car args) (cadr args)                                    
                 (if (>= (car args) (cadr args)) -1 1)))                   
    ( (3) (let* ((start (car args)) (end (cadr args))                      
                 (step (abs (caddr args))))
           (if (>=  end start)
             (do ((i start (+ i step))
                  (acc '() (push i acc)))
               ((>= i end) (nreverse acc)))
             (do ((i start (- i step))
                  (acc '() (push i acc)))
               ((<= i end) (nreverse acc))))))
    (t (error "ERROR, too many arguments for range"))))


;; (range-inc [[first] last [[step]]] ) includes LAST in the returned range
(defun range-inc (&rest args)
  (case (length args)
    ( (0) '())
    ( (1) (append (range (car args)) args))
    ( (2) (append (range (car args) (cadr args)) (cdr args)))
    ( (3) (append (range (car args) (cadr args) (caddr args))
          (list (cadr args))))
    (t (error "ERROR, too many arguments for range-inc"))))
```

Note: I wrote a [scheme version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51376529/6713615) as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a range function to generate a list of numbers.
We use the **do** "loop". If there is such a thing as a functional loop, then **do** macro is it. Although there is no recursion, when you construct a **do**, I find the thinking is very similar. You consider each variable in the **do** in the same way you consider each argument in a recursive call.

I use **list*** instead of **cons**. **list*** is exactly the same as **cons** except you can have 1, 2, or more arguments. **(list 1 2 3 4 nil)** and **(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 nil))))**.

```
(defun range (from-n to-n &optional (step 1)) ; step defaults to 1
  (do ((n from-n (+ n step))        ; n initializes to from-n, increments by step
       (lst nil (list* n lst)))     ; n "pushed" or "prepended" to lst

      ((> n to-n)                   ; the "recursion" termination condition
       (reverse lst))))             ; prepending with list* more efficient than using append
                                    ; however, need extra step to reverse lst so that
                                    ; numbers are in order
```

Here is a test session:

> CL-USER 23 > (range 0 10)
>
> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
>
> CL-USER 24 > (range 10 0 -1)
>
> NIL
>
> CL-USER 25 > (range 10 0 1)
>
> NIL
>
> CL-USER 26 > (range 1 21 2)
>
> (1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21)
>
> CL-USER 27 > (reverse (range 1 21 2))
>
> (21 19 17 15 13 11 9 7 5 3 1)
>
> CL-USER 28 >

This version does not work for decreasing sequences. However, you see that you can use **reverse** to get a decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to implement `(range n)` in a [tiny Lisp](https://github.com/zick/ZickStandardLisp) that just had `dotimes` and `setq` available:

```
(defun range (&rest args)
    (let ( (to '()) )
        (cond 
            ((= (length args) 1) (dotimes (i (car args))
                (push i to)))
            ((= (length args) 2) (dotimes (i (- (cadr args) (car args)))
                (push (+ i (car args)) to))))
    (nreverse to)))
```

Example:

```
> (range 10)
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

> (range 10 15)
(10 11 12 13 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, here is an analogue to user1969453's answer that returns a vector instead of a list:

```
(defun seq (from to &optional (step 1))
  (do ((acc (make-array 1 :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0))
       (i from (+ i step)))
      ((> i to) acc) (vector-push-extend i acc)))
```

Or, if you want to pre-allocate the vector and skip the 'vector-push' idiom:

```
(defun seq2 (from to &optional (step 1))
  (let ((size (+ 1 (floor (/ (- to from) step))))) ; size is 1 + floor((to - from) / step))
    (do ((acc (make-array size))
         (i from (+ i step))
         (count 0 (1+ count)))
        ((> i to) acc) (setf (aref acc count) i))))
```

Answer (score -1):

Recursive solution:

```
(defun range(min max &optional (step 1))
  (if (> min max)
    ()
    (cons min (range (+ min step) max step))))
```

Example:

```
(range 1 10 3)
(1 4 7 10)
```