# Fiddling with arguments order in Common Lisp functions

Tags: coding-style, common-lisp

After reading [Python's range() analog in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937520/pythons-range-analog-in-common-lisp), I went thinking that I didn't really like the  function interfaces used on the answers.

Three different lambda lists appear there:

1. `(start end &optional (step 1))`: both the `start` and `end` arguments are mandatory.
2. `(end &key (start 0) (step 1))`: IMHO, using keyword arguments seems overkill for such simple function, and they are there just to hide the fact that `end` and `start` do not appear in the natural order (i.e. first `start`, then `end`)
3. `(n &key (start 0) (step 1))` (from `alexandria:iota`): here, the optionality and order of the arguments are right, but at the expense of using a different abstraction.

The thing is that I would like to write `(range 6)` to generate `(0 1 2 3 4 5)` but also `(range 3 6)` to generate `(3 4 5)`. And actually, it is easily doable; for instance:

```
(defun range (start_or_end &optional end (step 1))
  (multiple-value-bind (start end)
      (if end
          (values start_or_end end)
          (values 0 start_or_end))
    (loop for n from start below end by step collect n)))
```

But well, I haven't seen this kind of argument fiddling in others code, and as a Lisp newbie I would like to know if that is an acceptable idiom or not.

**Update**: I have just discovered that Racket provides a [`range`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._range%29%29) function similar to the one I was proposing (an also the [`in-range`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-range#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-range%29%29) generator).

Comment: [lgtm](http://www.lgtm.in/)

Comment: Looks ugly to me. Invites errors. Hard to read. I would look at a call in the code and not know what it does. Lisp is a 'symbolic language': be as descriptive as possible, when in doubt. Avoid overly 'clever' code.

Answer (score 4):

As [Alessio Stalla pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29967223/1281433), there's nothing the matter with this, but it's not something you'll see very often.  Overloading by arity gets more complicated when the language permits optional and rest arguments.

I think the way that a case like this would typically be handled is to define things in terms of designators.  You could state that a range is determined by three values:  a start, an end, and a step.  Then you can say that a *range designator* is a list of length at most three, with the following semantics:

- `(n)` designates `(:start 0 :end n :step 1)`
- `(m n)` designates `(:start m :end n :step 1)`
- `(m n s)` designates `(:start m :end n :step s)`

Then you can do something like:

```
(defun range (&rest range-designator)
  (destructuring-bind (a &optional (b nil bp) (c nil cp))
      range-designator
    (multiple-value-bind (start end step)
        (cond
          (cp (values a b c))
          (bp (values a b 1))
          (t  (values 0 a 1)))
      (loop for x from start to end by step
           collect x))))
```

```
CL-USER> (range 5)
(0 1 2 3 4 5)
CL-USER> (range 2 7)
(2 3 4 5 6 7)
CL-USER> (range 2 7 3)
(2 5)
```

If you anticipate using range designators in other places, you can pull that inside stuff out a bit:

```
(defun to-range (designator)
  (destructuring-bind (a &optional (b nil bp) (c nil cp))
      designator
    (cond
      (cp (values a b c))
      (bp (values a b 1))
      (t  (values 0 a 1)))))

(defun range (&rest range-designator)
  (multiple-value-bind (start end step)
      (to-range range-designator)
    (loop for x from start to end by step collect x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is acceptable, although you don't encounter it very frequently. I'm pretty sure there are functions in the standard with such a signature but I can't remember any at the moment.

One example that I do remember is the JFIELD primitive in ABCL: http://abcl.org/trac/wiki/JavaFfi#FunctionJFIELDJFIELD-RAWSETFJFIELD

If you're concerned about performance, since "parsing" the lambda list has a cost, you can use compiler macros to avoid paying it, especially in a case like yours where the behaviour of the function is driven only by the number of arguments (as opposed to their types).